# MySql multi-table constraint

Tags: mysql, unique-constraint

A simple equity database has 3 tables: a ticker table, an exchange table, and a currency table. 
The  ticker table has two columns: a symbol column (ex: IBM), and a foreign key to a row in the exchange table. 
The exchange table has two columns: a name column (ex: NYSE), and a foreign key to a row in the currency table. 
The currency table has one column: a symbol (ex: USD). 
*(I've left out the primary keys column for each table).*

How do I enforce a constraint that there should not be the same ticker symbol twice for the same currency? i.e., I only want to allow one (IBM + USD). It is not enough to create a unique constraint on (ticker.symbol + ticker.exchange); (IBM + NASDAQ) is invalid if there is already (IBM + NYSE). I thought I could create a view that joined the ticker table and the currency table and create a unique index on (view.ticker + view.currency); however, as far as I can now tell, one cannot create an index on a view.

Comment: I'm not sure this constraint is a great idea: a company can actually be listed on two exchanges in the same currency - especially in Europe, where a company might be listed on exchanges in two countries, both in Euros.

Comment: That's fine -- I didn't want to overwhelm everyone with details, but the field is actually 'primary exchange'. There can be many secondary exchanges for each row in ticker table. However, the constraints of not having multiple rows with the same (ticker + currency) still seems reasonable. Thanks for giving this some thought though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't *think* it's possible to specify this constraint in MySQL, but you *could* use [triggers](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/triggers.html) to check that such combinations don't already exist (raising an error if they do); note however that you'd need to have triggers before insert on the ticker table and before update on all three tables.